# netFrameworkVersion in Azure App Services Api App

Tags: .net, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-webapps, azure-bicep

I'm configuring a api app in azure with bicep. This is a dotnet core 3.1 app. For netFrameworkVersion i provide 'v3.1', this however doesn't work. The deployment of the Bicep template does work, but my application does not. The value of .NET version is empty in the portal. [image]

When i manually change the version in the portal, and do an export of my app, the returned ARM template is sets netFrameworkVersion to 'v4.0'. I am very confused, what is happening here? I can't seem to find any documentation about this.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to specify the `CURRENT_STACK` metadata and the `netFrameworkVersion` property inside the `siteConfig` section:

```bicep
resource webapp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2018-11-01' = {
  ...
  properties: {
    ...
    siteConfig: {
      ...
      netFrameworkVersion: 'v6.0'
      metadata: [
        {
          name: 'CURRENT_STACK'
          value: 'dotnet'
        }
      ]
      ...
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thx for your help. Do you know where i can find documentation about this metadata parameters? there does not seem to be any on the official web/sites docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2018-11-01/sites?tabs=bicep .

Comment: Doesnt seems to be well documented but this sample from MS doc use that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/resource-manager-web-app

Comment: Observation: for .NET 6, the ARM template generated by Azure Portal has `CURRENT_STACK=dotnet`, and no longer `CURRENT_STACK=dotnetcore`, so I guess that would be the correct value for modern .NET versions.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft changed this with newer API versions, it now uses the property "linuxFxVersion" to set this:

```
resource webapp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-12-01' = {
...
   properties: {
     ...
     siteConfig: {
        ...
        linuxFxVersion: 'DOTNETCORE|6.0'
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to set the `netFrameworkVersion` in the `siteConfig` section:

```
resource functionapp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
...
   properties: {
     ...
     siteConfig: {
        ...
        netFrameworkVersion: '6.0'
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is it 6.0, or v6.0?

Comment: @Palec Just 6.0 exactly as I have it above

Comment: Have seen the other variant in many places. Will try once I upgrade the code of the App Service I am maintaining.

Answer (score 0):

As of 21 April 2023 the following worked for me. `metadata` within `siteConfig` was displayed as invalid, but adding metadata as a separate `config` resource worked:

```
resource webApplication 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
  name: 'my-app-name'
  ...
  properties: {
    ...
    siteConfig: {
      netFrameworkVersion: 'v6.0'
    }
  }
  resource meta 'config@2022-03-01' = {
    name: 'metadata'
    kind: 'string'
    properties: {
      CURRENT_STACK: 'dotnet'
    }
  }
}
```